# How to load static image in react native without require?

Tags: typescript, image, react-native, eslint-config-airbnb

I want to load image from my assets folder. I don't want to use require because it violates my eslint rules (I follow airbnb rules). I use typescript. Do you have any best practices for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import Image from '../assets/play.png'; // path to your image
```

use as

```
<Image source={Image} />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.